# What is special about Kovri over tor and other i2p-router?

Tags: kovri

Why a i2p-router over tor? Something with tcp and udp? maybe? It sounds lot more complex routing. Though tor is looking less safe lately

Comment: TOR uses virtual circuits meant for streams while I2P routing is more like a packet switching network were it is possible for different packets to take different routing paths.  TOR is used for session-based TCP routing while I2P is built on top of UDP routing.

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate label. The other question is "Why was I2P chosen over Tor for native Monero integration? " not why kovri over other i2p routers.